# How to handle two different Date libraries with same JPA Attribute Converters

Tags: java, jpa

In my Java EE project I'm using JPA 2.1 to get data from my Oracle DB. I mostly use Named and Criteria queries. The problem occurs when using Aliases with type of Tuple, which uses *java.util.Date*. But the other Named and Criteria queries uses *java.sql.Date* for LocalDate Converter.

So my JPA Attribute Converters look like this:

[using java.sql.Date]

```
import java.sql.Date;
...
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateAttributeConverter1 implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {
    // Implementation
}
```

And

[using java.util.Date]

```
import java.util.Date;
...
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateAttributeConverter2 implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {
    // Implementation
}
```

When using both of them in my project, there are problems with one of them when converting JDBC types to Java classes.

So is there any way to use both of Converters in my project?

Comment: Can you please tell us about the problems. Are you getting exceptions?

Comment: I guess the problem is using autoApply (true) on both Converters. Here is part of the error that I get: The object [25.6.2019 0:00], of class [class java.sql.Timestamp], from mapping [org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[balanceLastUpdate-->[viewName].balance_last_update]] with descriptor [RelationalDescriptor([classPath] --> [DatabaseTable(viewName)])], could not be converted to [class [B].

Comment: I'm still looking for workaround.